# How to Avoid any symbols in Variable

Tags: batch-file

I have created a batch file as below

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo  Type Below Requirements:
echo.
:username
set /p usr= Type Username:
if [!usr!]==[] goto username
:password
set /p pwd= Type Password:
if [!pwd!]==[] goto password
echo.
echo Your username is: !usr!
echo Your password is: !pwd!
```

It's working perfectly but I want to avoid any Symbol or space (ex: !@#$%^&*) to type in Username.

Is it Possible, Please Advice.

Comment: On a side note, instead of checking if `!usr!` or `!pwd!`  is null with `[!var!]==[]` You could use `if not defined !var! goto whatever`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `for /f` loop split the username on all alphanumeric characters.  Then if there's anything left, it's probably invalid.

```js
:username
set /p "usr=Username: "
if not defined usr goto username
for /f "delims=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789" %%I in ("!usr!") do (
    echo Username must not contain any non-alphanumeric characters.
    goto username
)
```

For extra credit, you can employ PowerShell to obfuscate the password entry from the console.  Here's a complete example:

```js
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo  Type Below Requirements:
echo.
:username
set /p "usr=Username: "
if not defined usr goto username
for /f "delims=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789" %%I in ("!usr!") do (
    echo Username must not contain any non-alphanumeric characters.
    goto username
)

set "psCommand=powershell -noprofile "$p=read-host -AsSecureString;^
$m=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal];$m::PtrToStringAuto($m::SecureStringToBSTR($p))""

:password
<NUL set /P "=Password: "
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`%psCommand%`) do set "pwd=%%I"
if not defined pwd goto password

echo.
echo Your username is: !usr!
echo Your password is: !pwd!
```